# php if else using $thisPage

Tags: php, html

I have a nav that based on the page I need to change href, and link text, but can't get it to work.

This is what I need

```
<?php
if ($thisPage=="Index-EN" || "Index-IT") {
?>
    <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="about"><?php echo MENU_ABOUT ?>AAA</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="gallery"><?php echo MENU_GALLERY ?></a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo MENU_CONTACTS_LINK_HOME ?>"><?php echo MENU_CONTACTS ?></a></li>
<?php
} else {
?>
    <li><a href="index.php#about" data-id="about"><?php echo MENU_ABOUT ?>BBB</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php#gallery" data-id="gallery"><?php echo MENU_GALLERY ?></a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo MENU_CONTACTS_LINK ?>"><?php echo MENU_CONTACTS ?></a></li>
<?php
}
?>
```

And this is what I tried, and I know it's wrong since makes the nav disappear

```
<?php
if ($thisPage=="Index-EN" || "Index-IT") {
echo '
    <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="about">' . MENU_ABOUT . 'AAA</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="gallery">' . MENU_GALLERY . '</a></li>
    <li><a href="' . MENU_CONTACTS_LINK_HOME . '">' . MENU_CONTACTS . '</a></li>'
} else {
echo '
    <li><a href="index.php#about" data-id="about">' . MENU_ABOUT . 'BBB</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php#gallery" data-id="gallery">' . MENU_GALLERY . '</a></li>
    <li><a href="' . MENU_CONTACTS_LINK_HOME . '">' . MENU_CONTACTS . '</a></li>'
}
?>
```

Comment: For your second exmple: You are missing the semicolon `;` after the echo statements

Comment: `$thisPage=="Index-EN" || "Index-IT")` must be `$thisPage=="Index-EN" || $thisPage=="Index-IT") `

Comment: *but can't get it to work* is no error description

Comment: To output errors, put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', 'On');` at the top of your code.

Comment: @Jens Well, being ignorant about coding, and having put the code with all its mistakes, and saying what happens to the page, I thought would be enough as error reporting ;)

Comment: Indeed the ; was missing, and found out I needed to remove the { and } to make the nav appear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if ($thisPage=="Index-EN" || "Index-IT")
```

This will always evaluate to `true` because of the second expression. You should explicitly add another `==` to check for equality:

```
if ($thisPage == "Index-EN" || $thisPage == "Index-IT")
```

Comment: Good, learned a bit more ;)
Now I need to fix a linking issue as the index.php#anchor-name don't work.

Answer (score 1):

When checking strings like this, use [strtolower](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) in your PHP, i.e:

```
 if (strtolower($thisPage) =="index-en" || strtolower($thisPage) == "index-it") {
```

Also, you need to check the `$thisPage` variable twice as above, which is why things were not working for you.

Comment: Is there a specific reason for it, since my page names are actually with caps (i.e. Index-EN)

Comment: Yes but can you guarantee that will *alway* be the case? If not, then `strtolower()` (or `strtoupper()` even) should be used to ensure that the condition fires each time. i.e., what happens when you enter the URI segment in lower-case?